# Remove Hyperlink of specif cell in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I've created a gridview, which all values (footer included) are hyperlinks, to export a detail in Excel.

All is working fine, except, when the value is 0, I don't want to permit the hyperlink, so it doesn't create a empty excel.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dtlist" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CssClass="table tabela caixa " CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="dtlist_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="true" >
<Columns >
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="LabelT" runat="server" Text="Total"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkA" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("/Export?name={0}, Eval("name")) %>' Text='<%# Eval("value","{0:#####,##0.00 €}") %>' />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblA" Text='<%# Eval("value","{0:#####,##0.00 €}") %>' Visible="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkTA" />
</FooterTemplate>
<FooterStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="alinha-meio" />
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the RowDataBound:

```
protected void dtlist_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        Total = 0;
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink hA = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkA");
        Label lA = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblA");

        if (hA.Text.ToDecimal() == 0)
        {
            hA.Visible = false;
            lA.Visible = true;
        }

        Total += ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row["Ano0"].ToDecimal();
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        HyperLink tA = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkTA");
        tA.NavigateUrl = String.Format("/ExportStock?name={0}","ZZZZ");
        tA.Text = Total0.StringEuro();
    }
}
```

I've tried to ask on the e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow, if the value of the Hyperlink is 0, but if one value on the column is 0 it disables all hyperlinks on that column.

How can I remove only for the 0 cell?

Thanks.

**CODE UPDATED**

Comment: How do you identify if hyperlink has value 0 or not?

Comment: like this
`HyperLink h0 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnk0");
            if(h0.Text.ToDecimal() == 0)
            {
                h0.NavigateUrl = "#";
            }`

Comment: You can do a thing take two control one hyperlink and another label.  Let say label is visible false by default. when condition doesn't meet then hide hyperlink and show the label instead.

Comment: The problem is the same.
If I make this:
`HyperLink hA = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("lnkA");
            Label lA = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblA");
            if (hA.Text.ToDecimal() == 0)
            {
                hA.Visible = false;
                lA.Visible = true;
            }`

If any lnk0 is 0, only displays the labels on all rows.

Comment: Please share whole code where you are performing this comparison.

Comment: just updated the code

Comment: OK, the code is fine but there's something to do with the format `{0:#####,##0.00 €}` you are trying to cast the text to decimal which is not possible because it contain a currency symbol and comma thus you are getting every result as zero. Strange behaviour what I'm seeing is that there's no runtime exception raised when you are casting to decimal. I am expecting something like format exception to be raised here . Well just remove comma and currency symbol before converting to decimal.

Comment: GREAT, just worked as you said.